# Can't bind to '..' since it isn't a known property

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I'm trying to create a Tinder-like swiping functionality for my Angular project, but for some reason I keep getting an error saying my property parentSubject isn't a known property of my card component. I did provide the @Input() annotation for the property, but somehow it is not recognised as a property.

```
//app.component.html
<div class="tbg">
  <div class="theader">
    <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="tlogo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbgwrap">
    <app-card [parentSubject]="parentSubject">
    </app-card>
    <div class="tcontrols">
      <div (click)='cardAnimation("swipeleft")'  class="tno"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div class="ti"><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      <div (click)='cardAnimation("swiperight")' class="tyes"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
//app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  parentSubject:Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {

  }

  cardAnimation(value: string) {
    this.parentSubject.next(value);
  }

}
```

```
//card.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('cardAnimator', [
      transition('* => swiperight', animate(750, keyframes(kf.swiperight))),
      transition('* => swipeleft', animate(750, keyframes(kf.swipeleft))),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class CardComponent  implements  OnInit{
  public tutors: Tutor[] = TUTORS;
  public index = 0;
  @Input() public  parentSubject!: Subject<string>;

  animationState: string | undefined;
  private _state: any;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.parentSubject.subscribe((event) => {
      this.startAnimation(event);
    });
  }


  startAnimation(state: string | undefined) {
    if (!this.animationState) {
      this.animationState = state;
    }
  }

  resetAnimationState(state: any) {
    this._state = state;
    this.animationState = '';
    this.index++;
  }
}
```

I don't know what else to try. I tried binding the property, calling it from my .ts component instead of from my .html file. I tried putting it in a constructor.

Comment: Remember, if your two components are declared in the same Module (in the array `declarations`) should work, else the module where you are declared your "AppComponent" should import the module where you are declared the "CardComponent" and in this modules you need  (futhermore include in the array `declarations`) also add in the array `exports` the component.